# Integration of Telerik MVC UI controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I'm using MVC 4 and trying to integrate Telerik MVC into.  I'm having several issues when trying to follow their documentation. Can somebody please lead me to some good examples?

Right now I'm trying to make drop down:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
            @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("DOBPicker")
            .Format("MMMM yyyy")
            .Value(model=>model.DOB.ToShortDateString()))
```

but the model is not recognized in the Value().

Has anybody done this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Kendo UI, it's Telerik's stuff for the web.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html